# How do I use Perl's Remote::Selenium::WebElement to verify the URL a hyperlink will take me to?

Tags: perl, xpath, selenium, webdriver

Seems like it should be straightforward but I can't seem to get to the bottom of it.

Here's the HTML I'm working with:

```
<li id="a" class="FILElevel3" onclick="changeMenu("b")">
<a onclick="stopBubble(event);" href="javascript:LinkPopup('/sub/URL.html')">Visible Text</a>
```

I'm able to find the element using XPaths:

`my $returned_asset = $sel->find_element("//*[\@class='LINKlevel3']");`

And I can verify this works because I'm able to extract the visible text from it:

`my $returned_name = Selenium::Remote::WebElement::get_text($returned_asset);`

I just can't seem to find the sequence to pull the HREF attribute from the element to put the link's URL into a verifiable string.  Should I be able to do this using WebElement's `get_attribute()` method?  I've tried variations on this:

`my $returned_URL = $returned_asset-> Selenium::Remote::WebElement::get_attribute("a/href");`

...where I've plugged in everything I could think of for that "a/href" string.  What should go in there?

In the end I'd like to be able to put "javascript:LinkPopup('/sub/URL.html')" into a string and verify that my URL is in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried

```
my $returned_asset = $sel->find_element("//*[\@class='LINKlevel3']/a");

my $returned_URL = $returned_asset->Selenium::Remote::WebElement::get_attribute("href");
```

Comment: Yes, this returned `undefined` unfortunately.  I think it's got something to do with the relationship between `a` and `href` but I'm stumped on what it could be.

Comment: i updated my answer, so not sure if you looked at it, while I was editing?

Comment: Eureka!  It even keeps the get_text() call intact using the more refined element.  Thanks!